# Tab bar opens camera view animation

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar, camera-view

I have a cameraviewController and I would like that when you press the bar button it will open the view with animation like WhatsApp with the circular transition animation.

Hope someone have some tutorial or code for that.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there is a way to write custom transition defined by Apple using custom UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. check it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)

If you are looking for drop in solution you may check [BubbleTransition](https://github.com/andreamazz/BubbleTransition)

Also there is a good library for further custom transitions called [Hero](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero).

For general usage of custom transition and tutorial, you can refer to Ray Wenderlich web, where you can find useful tips. [Swift custom transitions - Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173576/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-3)

Comment: good answer :D, writing your own is great experience, but links to multiple libraries ++

Comment: In fact if you get used to it, it is pretty fancy, but why to reinvent the wheel ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey first of all thanks about your comment but Do you have any code that can provide me exactly how to create the animation

Comment: Check out the BubbleTransition link, there is setup section in Readme file. How do you mean code to create the animation? The animation on your own or what kind of ? :)